# Which price in a package plan should be emphasized?

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, marketing

If in packages plans we have 3 plans where each one we show a number of views to the user (which is important to him) but at the same time we show the user the price.

Which one should we make it with larger font and bold?

Comment: This may be more suited to Graphic Design than user experience.

Comment: @MikeM no its user experience, because  i want to know whats going to affect the user more, I think from my side is the number of views, but am afraid that he will be mistaken as most websites show the price in a big font.

Comment: Can you add a mockup or wireframe to get a better idea of the problem?

Comment: It sounds more like a marketing question than UX. (I'd suggest you visit a lot of sites that do this and see what they do.)

Answer (score 1):

As a user and designer, I will always prefer to see prices upfront. No surprises, no hideous terms and conditions. Also, make sure to highlight what is included or excluded in that price.

Additionally, I'd suggest to check with your competitors. Check how they are doing, it will give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

Price is most important but it depends of the users you want to impact. Look at basecamp princing https://basecamp.com/pricing. They are going directly talking about money and features.

Answer (score 0):

While price is an important factor in the decision making process, it's the other factors that explain the difference in cost. For that reason I would make the views stand out.